# NVL Function in SQL

Tags: sql, nvl

what excatly 1 - NVL(up, 0) down this statement mean , is it giving me the contradiction of up ?

Comment: NVL returns `UP` if it is not null, else  zero. So if UP is not null  it will be subtracted from 1.

Comment: i see this line in a query where it should give me sum of down machines , soon after this i have sum(down) . what is the purpose of subtracting here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, `up` is a value that can take up to three values:  `0`, `1`, and `NULL`.

The `NVL()` function is a database-specific function for `COALESCE()`.  They do the same thing.

So, simply look at what the results are:

```
 up     1 - coalesce(up, 0)
  1               0
  0               1
NULL              1
```

So, it is "flipping the switch".  That is, when "up" is "true", then it switches it to "false".  It treats `0` as "false" for this purpose.